# How to access a string variable outside

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        String a = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
        String b = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value.PadLeft(3, '0');
        String c = TextBox1.Text.PadLeft(5, '0').ToString();
        String d = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
        String digit = a + b + c + d;


        try
        {
            OdbcConnection casetype = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=testcase;User=root;Password=root;Option=3;");
            casetype.Open();
            //************to get case type     
            string casetypequery = "select casename from casetype where skey=?";



            //************to get case type 
            OdbcCommand casetypecmd = new OdbcCommand(casetypequery, casetype);
            String casetypefromdropdown = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.ToString();
            casetypecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", casetypefromdropdown);
            using (OdbcDataReader casetypeMyReader = casetypecmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (casetypeMyReader.Read())
                {
                    String casename = casetypeMyReader["casename"].ToString();

                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ewa)
        {
            Response.Write(ewa);
        }
```

I am not able to access

```
String casename = casetypeMyReader["casename"].ToString();
```

which is inside while loop in my above code.
How can i access

> 'casename'

outside while loop?i want to use it to put the content in HtmlEditor(ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the variable outside the loop you need to declare it outside:

```
string casename = "some default value";
while (casetypeMyReader.Read())
{
    casename = casetypeMyReader["casename"].ToString();
}
// You can access casename here and it's value will either be the default one
// if the reader returned no rows or the last row being read.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare an Array or List of strings outside the loop, and save the casename values in that.

```
List<string> caseNames = new List<string>();
while (casetypeMyReader.Read())
{
    caseNames.Add(casetypeMyReader["casename"].ToString());
}
```

Now they're all in the array and you can access it wherever.

If there are duplicates, and you need unique values, you can do `caseNames.Distinct().ToList()` afterwards.

Comment: +1 for considering the fact that casename would be set multiple times inside of the while loop and assigning the values to an array.